# How to confrim the training using Libsvm is correct or not?

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

I have started doing training of two classes using LibSVM.

The training data is arranged like:
Training data of two classes (each class has 7128 images): (14256 X 2304)
Training label of two classes (each class has 7128 images (1's and -1's)): (14256 X 1)

```
model = svmtrain(training_label, training_data, '-s 0 -t 0 -c 1 -g 0.1')
```

I am getting this output:

```
..
WARNING: using -h 0 may be faster
*..*
optimization finished, #iter = 4625
nu = 0.024285
obj = -173.499920, rho = 13.995985
nSV = 577, nBSV = 189
Total nSV = 577


model = 

Parameters: [5x1 double]
  nr_class: 2
   totalSV: 577
       rho: 13.9960
     Label: [2x1 double]
sv_indices: [577x1 double]
     ProbA: []
     ProbB: []
       nSV: [2x1 double]
   sv_coef: [577x1 double]
       SVs: [577x2304 double]
```

Feature Vector:

```
figure
pos = find(training_label == 1);
neg = find(training_label == -1);
plot(training_data(pos,1), training_data(pos,2), 'ko', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b'); hold on;
plot(training_data(neg,1), training_data(neg,2), 'ko', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'g')
```

[image]

My question is how can I check the training is done correctly or not? and what is this shown at the output?

Comment: Did you try running the model against the training set? how was the error?

Comment: Above are the results of the model using the training set. How can I check the error?